# How to scale with the camera in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, viewport

I am trying to render a Sprite onto my phone screen. My world has a size of 100x100 units and I would like to split it into 10 equal rectangles (**10 x 100 units each**).

Each of them will be viewed as full screen and I want the camera to be able to scroll from one to another according to the character movement (as the character in the game reaches the halfway width of the rectangle).

The problem is that **the camera zooms in too much to the Sprite area and the Sprite rendered doesn't respect the aspect ratio of the PNG file.**

Should I use a shape render object such as a rectangle which would be the same size as the phone screen and fill the rectangle with parts of the Sprite, then somehow scale this shape render rectangle in order to preserve the aspect ratio of the PNG file?

Please advise me as to what is best?

Comment: hello - show us some screenshots to show how it looks like - the best would be also example how it actually should looks

Comment: I think scaling might be too expensive to implement. Maybe I should create the PNG file as a 9-patch and be mindful of drawing circles since they will most likely appear as ovals once stretched to fit the phone screen. what do you think

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify units then Orthographic camera has a accessible `zoom` field. But it is always best to specify what you want exactly.

If you want to have 10 "things" next to eachother and fitting on the camera I would just specify that.

```
int thingsWidth = 1; //1 could stand for meter
int amountOfThings = 10;

//give you texture/image/sprite the width of "thingsWidth"

@override
public void resize(float width, float height)
{
  float camWidth = thingsWidth * amountOfThings;
  //You probably want to keep the aspect ration of the window
  float camHeight = camWidth * ((float)height / (float)width);

  camera.viewportWidth = camWidth;
  camera.viewportHeight = camHeight;
  camera.update;
}
```

This is basically how the camera works with a regular screenViewport since we did not specify a specific viewport.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve exactly but `Scene2D` `Table` could work in your favor too. You just set `table.setFillParent(true);` then add 10 of your images to the table using something like `table.add(someActor).expand().fill()`. Now all your actors will fully expand and fill vertical and share the horizontal space. Now it does not matter how you setup your camera since the table takes care of the layout.

Comment: So this Table class object will accept 10 different Sprites or Textures each acting as an actor and will all be displayed at once on the phone screen growing vertically to fill it as well as horizontally. Can't I create it such that each of the Actors is visible one at time where each one fills the complete screen respecting the aspect ratio of the PNG file that creates the Sprite or Texture. Also, will it be possible to scroll thru them. @mennoGouw

Comment: @i_o My method shows how to put them all on your screen allongside eachother. Your sprites are 1:10 so it will not fill unless stretched or you have some strange 1:10 device. That is why I thought you wanted them next to eachother.

Comment: @i_o Before I edit my post I'd like to know why you "need" them next t eachother but only display one at a time? Perhaps you are just looking for a `ScrollPane`. As far as I understand the question you could just have them somewhere and on a user action you show the proper image.

Comment: Since I want to implement scene2d on the game. I wanted to use these 10 regions for my game background and scroll them based on character position. I think I will just try to create a large PNG file for the background, define texture regions and show each one individually so that it fills the entire phone screen . I will also like to loop thru them to have a finite background until character reaches end of level. @mennogouw

Comment: You can setup just one texture that is extending beyond the screen if you wish and use `background.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat)` now change the `source` of the larger texture depending on the position of the player. And voila, palax mapping made easy ;). Check this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603759/libgdx-how-to-repeat-background/23722518#23722518