# libgdx Infinitely repeating background texture

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've seen similar questions before but none helped me.
The player in my game can go to the right forever until he dies, but he can also go back.
I have a wall texture that I need to repeat forever on the top and bottom of the screen. I've seen answers where they say you need to put different values when drawing the texture at `srcX`, `srcY`, `srcWidth` and `srcHeight`, but when I do that the texture doesn't look anyting like the original. I set the texture to repeat with `wallTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat)`

The code I have to draw the wall on the top and bottom of the screen:

```
    spriteBatch.draw(wallTexture, -Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT - Constants.WALL_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.WALL_WIDTH / 2, Constants.WALL_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.WALL_WIDTH, Constants.WALL_HEIGHT, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 720, 64, false, false);
    spriteBatch.draw(wallTexture, -Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, -Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT - Constants.WALL_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.WALL_WIDTH / 2, Constants.WALL_HEIGHT / 2, Constants.WALL_WIDTH, Constants.WALL_HEIGHT, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 720, 64, false, false);
```

Thanks

Comment: Show what you did put so we can tell you what to change

Comment: I haven't really done anything yet, I've only draw the wall on the top and bottom of the screen but that's it, I'll add it to the question

Comment: You have read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23722518/1322271) and that really should work for you. The `srcX` and `srcY` values can be variable and will scroll your texture if you have set it to wrap on the specific axis. The `srcWidth` and `srcHeight` should obviously maintain the aspect ration of your original image or it will deform/stretch. Show me what's not working and I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It works, thank you!